# Need to fax HTML via .NET code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have 1 HTML page in a StringBuilder that consists of a number of tables.

After each table I put a page break for printing purposes. Now I need to fax this HTML page.

After each page, a break page should be faxed on another page.

I need to do this in either VB.NET or C#.

How can this be done?

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask... Why are you faxing HTML?

Comment: HTML is a good way to author content: He might just need to FAX some results, and chose HTML because it is a good way to lay it out.  I could also imagine a PDF, but a PDF is not as trivial to make.

Answer (score 3):

You need to render the page in order to FAX it (usually storing it in a multipage TIFF file).  You can do this by using an off-screen WebBrowser control and rendering it to a Graphics object that is backed by an Image and then encoding it into a TIFF.  You might be able to do this with any bitmap format.

Then you need to FAX it using this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Fax-XP-ing.aspx or this http://faxdotnet.codeplex.com/